# How to make scrollable tab in Android?

Tags: android, tabs, scrollable

I have 9 tab but in fill mode. I want to make these thabs scrollable. But i dont know the trick. I tried many methods but still nothing.

My Activity :

```
    package com.bani.fragment2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.WindowManager;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Fragment 1");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 3"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 4"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 5"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 6"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 7"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 8"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 9"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_CENTER);

    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final PagerAdapter adapter = new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener()     {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            switch(tab.getPosition()) {
                case 0:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                    toolbar.setTitle("Fragment 1");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                    toolbar.setTitle("Fragment 2");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                    toolbar.setTitle("Fragment 3");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(3);
                    toolbar.setTitle("Fragment 4");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(4);
                    toolbar.setTitle("Fragment 5");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(5);
                    toolbar.setTitle("Fragment 6");
                    break;
                case 6:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(6);
                    toolbar.setTitle("Fragment 7");
                    break;
                case 7:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(7);
                    toolbar.setTitle("Fragment 8");
                    break;
                case 8:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(8);
                    toolbar.setTitle("Fragment 9");
                    break;
                default:

                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                    toolbar.setTitle("Fragment 1");
                    break;
            }



        }


        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

And this is my layout with Tab:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help me to solve my problem, I tried to set tab gravity to MODE_SCROLLABLE and other way but still not working for me.

Comment: I think, this tutorial will be very helpful to you : http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Comment: Just follow this official android documentation 

https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-swipe-view

Answer (score 46, accepted):

> I tried to set tab gravity to MODE_SCROLLABLE

That is not a gravity value. That is a value to be passed to `setTabMode()` on the `TabLayout` (`tabs.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE)`).

[This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/DesignSupport/TabLayout) from [this book](https://commonsware.com/Android) has an activity that toggles between three fixed tabs and ten scrollable tabs:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2012-15 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    https://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.tablayout;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private SampleAdapter adapter;
  private TabLayout tabs;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ViewPager pager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);

    adapter=new SampleAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    tabs=(TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(pager);
    tabs.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.actions, menu);

    return(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId()==R.id.fixed) {
      item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());

      if (item.isChecked()) {
        adapter.setPageCount(3);
        tabs.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
      }
      else {
        adapter.setPageCount(10);
        tabs.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
      }

      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      tabs.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(adapter);

      return(true);
    }

    return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 29):

Simply just put  `app:tabMode="scrollable"`  inside the xml.

**Eg:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:tabMode="scrollable"
    app:tabTextColor="#ccc"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp" />
```

Comment: Just follow this official android documentation 

https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-swipe-view

Answer (score 9):

Set the Value of setTabMode to **TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE**

```
tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
```

And, you will be able to scroll tabs horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

For Kotlin Users here is the code

```
val tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs) as TabLayout

tabLayout.tabMode = TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE
```