# How to create a horizontally scrollable header in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, dynamic, header, scrollable

guys I am developing an Android Studio, and I would like to create a scrollabe header, a similar one that this app has: [Donald Trump Soundboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.berrybongobrother.donaldtrumpsoundboard).

Do you know any lectures on youtube or anywhere where I can learn a required skills to create such a header?

Comment: Hi. Please note this type of question is specifically off-topic for StackOverflow because you are asking for tutorials and other learning resources

Comment: Hi @Lexi. You're right. I really need to know it. What should I do then?

Comment: I would try to find a forum where discussion like this is allowed. Usually something like reddit or similar has a community that allows this type of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a scrollable Tab Layout, I have created an android library that does just that. It has custom animations too if you're into that. You can take a look [here](https://github.com/tompee26/FunTabLayout)
 and see if it suits your purpose.

Comment: I tried out your sample, now I could created a really fine scrollable bar. I have a quetion though. If I have buttons in the different Fragments, how should I attach different activites to the diferrent segments where I can use the buttons with OnClicklistener?

Answer (score 0):

I just saw the app, the one you are talking about is swipe​ view. The tabs are not fix rather it moves. It has been asked here( [How to make scrollable tab in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35815615/how-to-make-scrollable-tab-in-android) )