# How to make the selector under tabs to scroll to the selected tab?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-tablayout

[image: tablayout with scroll]

I want to scroll the selector(pink line) to the next tab(on-fillup). my fragments are scrolling but the selector is unable to scroll. can anyone help?

**MainActivity.java**

```
//Adding the tabs using addTab() method
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("On Reserved"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("On Fill-up"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
```

**activity_main.java**

```
<!-- our tablayout to display tabs  -->
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

<!-- View pager to swipe views -->
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Comment: should you not post the relevant code also?

Comment: check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35815615/how-to-make-scrollable-tab-in-android)

Comment: I tried it @JunJieWang but it doesn't work for me. thank you. more help appreciated.

Comment: If your tabs are not being selected with the pager move, have you called this method tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to assign `tablayout` in `viewpager` like below code

```
// listener for tablayout when you select tab for change view
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(this);
 // assign tablayout in viewpager
 viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
```

this is override method when you tap on tab then `viewpager` is change

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mBinder.viewPager);//This line is important to make tab scrollable with viewpager and it should be after set adapter to viewpager
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution

TabTextColor sets the color for the title of the tabs, passing a ColorStateList here makes tab change colors in different situations such as selected, active, inactive etc. TabIndicatorColor sets the color for the indiactor below the tabs.

```
tabLayout.setTabTextColors(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this, R.drawable.tab_selector));
tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.indicator));
```

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This problem occur when you dont set viewpager with tablayout and viceversa too. So, please add following lines to your code...

```java
PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), nooftabs);
viewpager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewpager, true);
```

Hope this may help you